# Как можно получить число, которое не известно заранее, но легко получить после наступления какого-то события?

Tags: алгоритм, случайные-числа

Мне нужно создать алгоритм, который будет будет генерировать случайные числа на основе seed-числа. Сам алгоритм доступен любому пользователю в мире и при наличии правильного seed любой может получить ту же последовательность чисел.
В момент X пользователи должны получить seed число и таким образом они смогут рассчитать последовательность. К этому числу есть следующие требования

- Его не возможно рассчитать до нужного момента. При этом допускается получение числа в диапазоне до 4-5 часов от момента X
- Число легко проверить любому пользователю
- На генерацию числа невозможно (или очень сложно) повлиять

Вопрос: как можно получить такое число?

Comment: Сервер, который будет по определенному запросу возвращать это число?

Comment: На основе каких-нибудь биржевых котировок.

Comment: Вопросов очень много. Каким образом это может быть алгоритм генерации СЛУЧАЙНЫХ чисел на основе числа seed. Если все могут его получить? Т.е. условно зная seed 12345 - мы получает последовательность СЛУЧАЙНЫХ чисел. По идее, то что вы хотите это просто обычная функция - подаем число, на выходе получаем последовательность. Например md5 удовлетворяет вашим условиям.

Comment: чем вам `srandom` не устраивает? `#include <stdlib.h>` из открытых исходников.

Comment: @KordDEM согласен, тут правильнее говорить про псевдослучайные числа. Вопрос именно в том, как получить число, которое подается в функцию, чтобы оно удовлетворяло требованиям что я написал выше. Пока самые близкий вариант - биржевые котировки про которые написал Кирилл Малышев

Comment: Другой вариант - погода в 10 - 20 - 100 (выбрать нужное количество) населенных пунктах в час X.